# Can I use HTTP to access system directories?

Tags: rest, http, get, request

I have a canned database running like this

I have the request and the canned database server on the same system.

```
starting canned on port 3000 for ./
request: get /home/abc/def/canned/example/comment/any.get.json not found
request: get /home/abc/Desktop/hello not found
request: get /home/abc/Desktop/hello.json not found
```

My GET request looks like this (on the same system)

```
GET http://10.0.x.xx:3000/home/abc/Desktop/hello.json
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the absolute path, you must use a path which is relative to the HTTP server's document root. For example, if your server is using `/home/abc/` as the document root you would use the URL `http://10.0.x.xx:3000/Desktop/hello.json`